# How to use perl script to monitor whether a process is finished?

Tags: perl

I use    system "xxxxx"    in perl to execute some command in linux.
I have a batch of commands to execute so that I need to know when the last command is finished that I can send out the next one.
I don't want to use sleep(**) because I have no idea how long each command will executed.
Is there a way that I can monitor the when the command is finished?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Huh? `system(...)` will block until the command is complete. You know when the last command is finished because execution of your Perl script moves on to the next statement.

Answer (score -1):

You could open a named pipe and wait for it to close:

```
open(PROC, "-|", "/path/to/process") or die "can't open process: $!";
# do something 
close(PROC) or die "can't close process: $!";
```

The `close` statement will make the perl script wait for the process to finish.